# Android: AutoCompleteTextView's suggestions not clickable inside Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build a dialog box that contains an AutoCompleteTextView to prompt the user to enter information. While most everything works, wherein the autocomplete presents the correct suggestions as loaded from a database, upon clicking the suggestions nothing happens, and the Text field does not get filled with the autocomplete suggestion. Upon clicking the suggestions, a cursor appears as if to edit the suggestions themselves, although that does nothing either. I'm running this on a version 4.3 device, so I don't believe that's the problem.

The java code for implementing the Alert Dialog is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ChosenGroupName";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.tperm.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    final String previousGroupName = settings.getString("groupName", "No Group Specified");
    final SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor = settings.edit();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final SamplesDataSource mSamplesDataSource = new SamplesDataSource(
            this);
   mSamplesDataSource.open();
   mSamplesDataSource.addGroupNameifUnique("No Group Specified");
   List<String> groupNames = mSamplesDataSource.getAllGroupNames(true);
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.group_name_dialog);
   dialog.setTitle("Please Enter a Group Name for the Samples");

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(builder.getContext(),R.layout.group_name_dialog,R.id.group_name_autocomplete,groupNames);

  LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_name_dialog,null);

  final  AutoCompleteTextView groupNameAutocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.group_name_autocomplete);
  groupNameAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
  groupNameAutocomplete.setThreshold(1);
  groupNameAutocomplete.setPadding(0, 100, 100, 0);


  builder.setView(v)
  .setNegativeButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
          if(groupNameAutocomplete.getText()!=null){
              String chosenGroupName = groupNameAutocomplete.getText().toString();
              prefseditor.putString("groupName", chosenGroupName);
              prefseditor.commit();
              mSamplesDataSource.addGroupNameifUnique(chosenGroupName);
              dialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Name is: "+ chosenGroupName +
                      ".  You may change this by going into the settings menu.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else{
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No group name selected, you may use the last group name used for this system" +
                    " by selecting the \"use last group name\" button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
   })
   .setPositiveButton("Use Last Group name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Name is: "+ previousGroupName +
                      ".  You may change this by going into the settings menu.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();// We will be getting the group name string from the prefs
            //and we already loaded the last group name.
        }
});
  builder.show();

}
```

The xml code for the Dialog's custom view is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/group_name_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Group Name" >

    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:  I figured out my problem.  It was in the line instantiating the ArrayAdapter to be used for the autocomplete suggestions.  In the resource argument, you can see that I specified the AutoCompleteTextView itself, rather than ndroid.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line as it should be.

The correct line would be as follows:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(builder.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,R.id.group_name_autocomplete,groupNames);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  I figured out my problem.  It was in the line instantiating the ArrayAdapter to be used for the autocomplete suggestions.  In the resource argument, you can see that I specified the AutoCompleteTextView itself, rather than android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line as it should be.

The correct line would be as follows:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(builder.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,R.id.group_name_autocomplete,groupNames);
```